# Matching function arguments in generic priority queue type

Tags: c++

I use an external library which provides a generic priority queue type implementation.
Priority queue's class (declared in a header file, call it priorityQueue.h) is

```
template <typename KeyType, typename DataType, template <typename datatype> class   StorageType>
class PriorityQueue {...};
```

which contains an insert function:

```
//Insert a key-value pair to the priority queue
void insert( const KeyType& key, const DataType& data, const DescriptorType ptr = 0)
```

I need this priority queue to store items of the struct below into:

```
 struct certificate
 {
    float tfail;
    typename GraphType::NodeIterator n;
    unsigned int ne, citem; 
 };
```

so i've implemented this function:

```
void storeCertificates(const NodeIterator& u, int node_or_edge)
{
//representation: (ne, idn, tfail), for a node identified by idn if we have a min cert (ne= 0), or a tail of an edge identified by idn if we have a pr cert (ne=1)
certificate cert;

int ne;
if(node_or_edge == 0) //min certificate
    ne = 0;
else              //prim certificate
    ne = 1;

cert.ne = ne;
cert.n = u;
cert.tfail = u->tfail;
cert.citem = 0;

c.insert( cert.tfail, cert, cert.citem); //<=========
}
```

which stores a cert item into a priority queue defined as:

```
 typedef PriorityQueue< WeightType, NodeIterator, HeapStorage>   PriorityQueueType;
 PriorityQueueType c;
```

In compile time, i get the following error:

```
td_dijkstra_and_os.h:680:2: error: function does not match call to  
‘PriorityQueue<float, std::_List_iterator<ALNode<node, edge> >, HeapStorage>::insert(float&, TD_Dijkstra_OS<DynamicGraph<AdjacencyListImpl, node, edge> >::certificate&, unsigned int&)’
td_dijkstra_and_os.h:680:2: note: candidate is:
/home/danuser/eCOMPASS/pgl/include/Structs/Trees/priorityQueue.h:132:10: σημείωση: void PriorityQueue<KeyType, DataType, StorageType>::insert(const KeyType&, const DataType&, PriorityQueue<KeyType, DataType, StorageType>::DescriptorType) [with KeyType = float, DataType = std::_List_iterator<ALNode<node, edge> >, StorageType = HeapStorage, PriorityQueue<KeyType, DataType, StorageType>::DescriptorType = unsigned int*, PQSizeType = unsigned int]
/home/danuser/eCOMPASS/pgl/include/Structs/Trees/priorityQueue.h:132:10: σημείωση:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘TD_Dijkstra_OS<DynamicGraph<AdjacencyListImpl, node, edge> >::certificate’ to ‘const std::_List_iterator<ALNode<node, edge> >&’
```

Please, provide a correct way to use this insertion function for my implementation.

EDIT: Can someone provide an implementation of this by using std::priority_queue or, even better boost's priority queue?

Comment: You have a `PriorityQueue` whose `DataType` is `NodeIterator`, not `certificate`. 
W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating instance for

```
     PeiorityQueueType c;
```

of type

```
      PriorityQueue< WeightType, NodeIterator, HeapStorage>
```

Once you create an instance following insert function will b grnerated by the compiler.

```
      void insert(const WeightType& key, const NodeItrator& data, const DescriptorType ptr = 0);
```

but you are calling insert function as

```
       c.insert( cert.tfail, cert, cert.citem);
```

which is of

```
     template<const float&, const certificate&, unsigned int >.
```

Which controverse the datatype you are declared. So, Change the calling insert functions datatype for function.

Answer (score 2):

`DataType` of the queue is `NodeIterator`, but you are trying to insert `certificate`.